# Possible to debug/run aspnet5 application in IIS via VS2015

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to debug and run an ASP.Net5 MVC6 application via IIS and VS2015 using the current preview? (CTP5).

When I look at the available project options(project properties/Debug/Debug target) I only have IIS express available in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 8):

Currently ASP.NET 5 hosting for Visual Studio only supports the following:

- Hosting with IIS Express
- Self host with the web command (or any other command)

Support for IIS is on our backlog but it may not make the initial release. We are likely to specifically target IIS Express until most features are implemented. After that we will add support for IIS.

Comment: If IIS debugging and deploying tooling isn't yet complete, is IIS currently usable as a deployable platform but with some manual deployment? i.e. build, run command line tool, manual copy etc? I was hoping to deploy apps against local IIS and also Azure IIS. If so is there an article describing what steps are required to do it "manually"

Comment: @tim you can publish to the file system for that scenario.

Comment: Was about to ask the same thing, I always use IIS to host the project I am working on, to quickly see changes I made in CSS and JS. But this seems no longer possible and we have to build/publish to get it in IIS for now. A LOT of hassle :(

Comment: @Wim, I use the same workflow with my development, and just attach to process when I need to debug... This also means that I can't really try the new VSCode editor either, as I can't just Build -> Alt + Tab -> F5

Comment: Any new status on this?